# navigation bar not showing when uploaded online

Tags: html, css

kind sir's does anybody know why my navigation bar is not showing when i upload it in a free web host (x10hosting and 000webhost) but when i run it in localhost its perfectly working.

this is when i run it in localhost
[image]

and this what happens when i run it online 
[image]

this is the html code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.php"><img src="img\home.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:3px; width:16px; height:16px;">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="speakers.php"><img src="img\speakers.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:4px; width:15px; height:13px;">Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><img src="img\about.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:3px; width:13px; height:12px;">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php"><img src="img\contact.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:14px;">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservation.php"><img src="img\reservation.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:5px; width:14px; height:13px;">Reservation</a></li>
            <li><a href="signOut.php" id="signOut"><img src="img\signOut.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:14px; height:14px;">Sign Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="myAccount.php" id="user" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><img src="img\user.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:12px;"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="signUp.php" id="signUp"><img src="img\signUp.png" style="margin-bottom:-1px; margin-right:6px; width:13px; height:11px;">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="signIn.php" id="signIn"><img src="img\signIn.png" style="margin-bottom:-2px; margin-right:6px; width:14px; height:13px;">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="adminControl.php" id="adminControl"><img src="img\admin.png" style="margin-bottom:-3px; margin-right:6px; width:15px; height:16px;">Admin control</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Speaker Reservation</a>
</nav>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img1" src="img/homepage-image1.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img2" src="img/homepage-image2.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img id="img3" src="img/homepage-image3.jpg">
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>

<div id="dots">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

</div>

<div id="index-welcome"><p>Welcome to Online Speaker Reservation. We are an organization established in 2005 by Rey Vibal, which engages the skills of performing artists directors and writers for the purpose of tuition in the performing arts, theatrical and film production, corporate training, wellness and sharing methodologies.</p></div>

<div id="footer" >Copyright 2017</div>

<script>
$(function() 
    {
        var pull = $('#pull');
        menu = $('nav ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();
        $(pull).on('click', function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function()
        {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) 
            {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
</script>

<script>
function ifAdmin() 
{ 
       document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotLogin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("user").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == true) 
        //if login
        {
            if($_SESSION['type'] == 1)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifAdmin();</script>";  
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['type'] == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotAdmin();</script>";
            }
        }
        //if not login
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotLogin();</script>";   
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the css codes

```
/*navigation bar*/

    nav 
    {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #342E2D;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;

    }
    nav ul 
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
    }
    nav li 
    {
        display: inline;
    }
    nav a 
    {
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 60px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
    }
    nav li a 
    {

        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    nav li:last-child a 
    {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    nav a:hover, nav a:active 
    {
        background-color: #1E1D1C;
    }
    nav a#pull 
    {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Clearfix */

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    .clearfix {
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    #signIn, #signUp, #signOut, #adminControl, #user
    {
        float:right;
    }

    #adminControl
    {
        width:130px;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the file is not called "styles.css" but "Styles.css"? Can you not show a link to the uploaded page where it is not working?

Comment: Looks fine. have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: thanks @NineBerry  im such an idiot. i already know that when css is not working i have to clear the cache but i  dont know that it is also needed when your site is online i thought it only happen when in local host. btw it there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: See for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239921/101087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me Make sure to clear cache u can achive this by

**Option1:**

Try opening the browser in Incognito(chrome) mode.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

private(IE)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

**Option2**

Just clear the browsers cache.

I had a cache problem few times using webhost00

Comment: thanks it works. i forgot to clear the cache. btw is there a way to prevent this? or it only happens in some free webhost?

Comment: Yes, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358998/clearing-cache-once-on-deploy

Answer (score 1):

It appears like the CSS styling isn't loading at all. Check the location of your CSS file on your webhost against the stylesheet link in your HTML file.